# segmentation fault with llvm-ir

Tags: llvm

Can anyone tell me what's the problem with this LLVM-IR code that causes segmentation faulta and how to solve it?

```
%mytype = type {i32 (...)**}
%mytype2 = type {i32, %mytype**}
...
%obj = load %mytype2** %myobj
%get = getelementptr inbounds %mytype2* %obj, i32 0, i32 1
%ml = mul i32 4, 4
%naj = call noalias i8* @_Znaj(i32 %ml)
%cast = bitcast i8* %naj to %mytype**
store %mytype** %cast, %mytype*** %get

%get2 = getelementptr %mytype** %get, i32 0

%ld = load %mytype** %get2
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
%get2 = getelementptr %mytype** %get, i32 0
```

is illegal, as the type of `%get` is `%mytype***`, not `%mytype**`. Also, since `gep something i32 0` is always a nop, I'm guessing you really wanted something else here anyway.

In general, I recommend using [LLVM's verify pass](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#verify-module-verifier) (run `opt -verify`) on your IR to check whether it's legal or not. You can also try my [IR editor plugin for Eclipse](http://amishne.github.io/llvm-ir-editor/), which doesn't work as well but gives you a nice GUI feedback:

> [image: type error on the gep]

You should fix the code to be the legal:

```
%get2 = load %mytype*** %get
%ld = load %mytype** %get2
```

If you get a segfault at runtime when running those lines, it means either the first load or the second load accessed non-allocated memory. To track down the reason for that, you need to look into how you allocate the `%myobj` object and its fields.

Comment: you are right. I should have used %get2 = load %mytype*** %get instead of %get2 = getelementptr %mytype** %get, i32 0. However, my problem is something other than syntax error: I get seg fault for these instructions:(1) %get2 = load %mytype*** %get (2)  %ld = load %mytype** %get2 (3) %content = getelementptr %mytype* %ld, i32 2

Comment: @user1723583 do you get a segfault when building/processing the IR, or a segfault when running the code generated from this IR?

Comment: @user1723583 then it sounds like the problem is that you have not allocated the object properly; I've updated my answer to address that.